# Aws cdk. How to restore nuget packages from codeartifacts when deploying .net lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create a AWS cdk project that deploys a .net lambda function. I have followed the following blog post:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/create-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-net-lambda-functions-with-aws-cdk-pipelines/

My issue is now i need to restore nuget packages that are stored in codeartifacts, but i can't get it to work. I tried the following:

```
class SampleLambdaStack: Stack
{
    public SampleLambdaStack(Construct scope, string id, StackProps props = null) : base(scope, id, props)
    {
        // Commands executed in a AWS CDK pipeline to build, package, and extract a .NET function.
        var buildCommands = new[]
        {
            "cd /asset-input",
            "export DOTNET_CLI_HOME=\"/tmp/DOTNET_CLI_HOME\"",
            "export PATH=\"$PATH:/tmp/DOTNET_CLI_HOME/.dotnet/tools\"",

            // Restore nuget packages from codeartifacts
            "dotnet tool install -g AWS.CodeArtifact.NuGet.CredentialProvider",
            "dotnet codeartifact-creds install",
           @"dotnet nuget add source -n codeartifact $(aws codeartifact get-repository-endpoint --domain my_domain --domain-owner 111122223333 --repository my_repo --format nuget --query repositoryEndpoint --output text)""v3/index.json""",
            "dotnet nuget list source",


            "dotnet build",
            "dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools",
            "dotnet lambda package -o output.zip",
            "unzip -o -d /asset-output output.zip"
        };
            
        new Function(this, "LambdaFunction", new FunctionProps
        {
            Runtime = Runtime.DOTNET_6,
            Handler = "SampleLambda::SampleLambda.Function::FunctionHandler",

            // Asset path should point to the folder where .csproj file is present.
            // Also, this path should be relative to cdk.json file.
            Code = Code.FromAsset("./src/SampleLambda", new AssetOptions
            {
                Bundling = new BundlingOptions
                {
                    Image = Runtime.DOTNET_6.BundlingImage,
                    Command = new[]
                    {
                        "bash", "-c", string.Join(" && ", buildCommands)
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    }
}
```

"dotnet nuget list source" command shows:

```
Registered Sources:
  1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  2.  codeartifact [Enabled]
      /tmp/DOTNET_CLI_HOME/.nuget/NuGet/v3/index.json
```

When AWS tries to restore projects, I Get the following error:

```
error NU1301: The local source '/tmp/DOTNET_CLI_HOME/.nuget/NuGet/v3/index.json' doesn't exist.
```

So my question is how do you restore nuget packages from codeartifacts, when deploying a .net lambda function?